# Is it possible to copy only visible lines in Sublime Text?

Tags: sublimetext3

Is there any way to just copy the visible lines after code folding? For example if I had a chunk of collapsed code like so:

```
.selector 1 { ...
}

.selector 2 { ...
}
```

and I only wanted to copy the visible lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll show you how I accomplish this task. I list only the required steps because my video has some superfluous ones.

Given the following code:

```
.selector 1 { ...
}

.selector 2 { ...
}
```

[image]

1. `⌘+A`, `⌘+K`, `⌘+1` to fold all code
2. Use cursor to select `.selector`
3. `⌘+⌃+G` to select all `.selector`
4. `←` to move to beginning of lines
5. `⌘+⇧+→` to select entire lines
6. `⇧+←` to unselect folded portions of code
7. `⌘+C` to copy
8. `⌘+V` to paste
9. Use cursor to select newly pasted lines
10. `⌘+⇧+L` to put cursor on all lines
11. `⌘+→` to move to end of lines
12. `}` to add closing brackets to all lines

It's not as simple as a highlight, copy, and paste, but it gets the job done fairly quickly if you've memorized all the keyboard shortcuts. There are variations of the same strategy you can use. For example, you can highlight all the yellow ellipses (the folded code), delete them, and then all that's left is the text you want.

Comment: This answer is basically just _"Select all the bits that are visible in a way that only works for this content"_

Answer (score 0):

Converted this for windows users with a bit more explanation. The core issue here is that when you select the content you want to avoid selecting the ... bit, as that represents the folded code.

What needs to be done is:

1. CTRL-LeftClick at the beginning of each line you wish to copy. (This will leave a cursor at each position.)
2. Press CTRL-L to select all of those lines of content.
3. Then Press SHIFT-LeftArrow to UNSELECT the ... bit at the end.
4. Now press CTRL-C and you have a copy of the unhidden (unfolded) content only.

Hope this helps a bit.